# Issue with Angular flex

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have got a basic flexbox grid. If I move the `ngFor` loop into a component (`<comp-ngfor-testGrid></comp-ngfor-testGrid>`) the flex is broken.

The `<comp-ngfor-testGrid>` on the DOM causes the issue.  I would like to remove it and keep only the content of the component `<comp-ngfor-testGrid>`.

`:host {}` is not the solution because the `<comp-ngfor-testGrid>` still exist...

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  div {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
testGrid = [4,5,6];
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of testGrid ">
    {{item}}
  </div>
  <comp-ngfor-testGrid></comp-ngfor-testGrid>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the use of one-extend-input class? and <comp-ngfor-testGrid>

Comment: @RishabVaigankar sorry, my bad I make a correction to the selector. <comp-ngfor-testGrid> is a component containing   <div *ngFor="let item of testGrid ">{{item}}</div> when the code is nested into a component the flex is broken. I would like to remove the component tag name from the dom and keep only the content.... something like that...

Comment: If you want remove the structural div created by the angular selector, you could just move that part out of it's own component and put it's HTML into this component.